# Why my comparison with an HEX enum fails?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am seeing a weird issue whe comparing a HEX value stored into an enum and a value read for a register, I have defined my CHIPID as follows

```
enum {
  BME_280_1_CHIPID = 0x60,
  BME_280_2_CHIPID = 0x58,
};
```

I have this snippet of code in my driver where the CHIP ID is check

```
  uint8_t id = read8(BME280_REGISTER_CHIPID);
  if ( ( id != BME_280_2_CHIPID)  || (id != BME_280_1_CHIPID) ){

    #ifdef DEBUG
        uint8_t value = read8(BME280_REGISTER_CHIPID);
        debugPrint("BME280 DEBUG: read BME280_CHIPID ");
        debugPrint(value,HEX);
        debugPrint( " expected ");
        debugPrint(BME_280_1_CHIPID,HEX);
      debugPrint( " or ");
      debugPrintLn(BME_280_2_CHIPID,HEX);
    #endif
        return false;
  }
```

my read8() funtion is

```
uint8_t Adafruit_BME280::read8(byte reg)
{
  uint8_t value;
    Wire1.beginTransmission((uint8_t)_i2caddr);
    Wire1.write((uint8_t)reg);
    Wire1.endTransmission();
    Wire1.requestFrom((uint8_t)_i2caddr, (byte)1);
    value = Wire1.read();

  return value;
}
```

However, the debug shows

```
BME280 DEBUG: read BME280_CHIPID 58 expected 60 or 58
BME280 MISSING!
```

What's happening?

Thanks in advance,

regards!

Comment: Note: `value != a || value != b`. Unless `a == b` then one of them is `true` for sure. Change it to `&&`.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `a == b`,  `value` never changes

Comment: @ndarkness No, one of the values is `0x60` (96), the other is `0x58` (94). All numbers are unequal to at least one of them. For instance, `BME_280_1_CHIPID != BME_280_2_CHIPID`.

Comment: did you care for the endianness of the data?

Comment: @ndarkness read it as `id != 0x58 || id != 0x60`. It's **always true**, it's `&&` instead of `||`.

Comment: This usually comes from translating "x is not a or b" into "x is not a or x is not b", which is not what it means.

Comment: But I want so, I want that  if none of those values are in the id, then I will go into the condition

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: "I want that if none of those values are in the id" ... and currently you enter the loop if one of the values is not equal to the id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution as Andriano Repetti told

```
  uint8_t id = read8(BME280_REGISTER_CHIPID);
  if ( ( id != BME_280_2_CHIPID)  && (id != BME_280_1_CHIPID) ){

    #ifdef DEBUG
        uint8_t value = read8(BME280_REGISTER_CHIPID);
        debugPrint("BME280 DEBUG: read BME280_CHIPID ");
        debugPrint(value,HEX);
        debugPrint( " expected ");
        debugPrint(BME_280_1_CHIPID,HEX);
      debugPrint( " or ");
      debugPrintLn(BME_280_2_CHIPID,HEX);
    #endif
        return false;
  }
```